# DB2 Alias for Concatenated string in Select statement

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to do the following SELECT statement in DB2 stored procedure:

```
FOR c AS ( SELECT o.id id
                    ,o.col1 col1
                    ,o.title title
                    ,o.locale locale
                    ,lower(desc1.detail1) CONCAT lower(desc1.detail2) CONCAT lower(desc1.detail3) CONCAT lower(desc1.detail4) description
                    ,lower(absc1.detail1) || lower(absc1.detail2) || lower(absc1.detail3) || lower(absc1.detail4) abstract
                FROM table_name o
                INNER JOIN desc_table ON o.id = desc1.some_id
                    AND o.desc1 = desc1.id
                INNER JOIN table_detail absc1 ON o.id = absc1.owner_id
                    AND o.abstract = absc1.id
                WHERE o.id = xid
                ) DO
```

and taking the following error:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0789N  The data type for parameter or SQL variable "DESCRIPTION" is not supported in the  routine, compound SQL statement, or parameter list of a cursor value constructor.  LINE NUMBER=...  SQLSTATE=429BB
```

The problem is in `lower(desc1.detail1) CONCAT lower(desc1.detail2) CONCAT lower(desc1.detail3) CONCAT lower(desc1.detail4) description` line
Seems that alias `description` is not appropriate for concatenated strings.

The same situation is for:

```
lower(absc1.detail1) || lower(absc1.detail2) || lower(absc1.detail3) || lower(absc1.detail4) abstract
```

Maybe You have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding AS:  `lower(desc1.detail1) CONCAT lower(desc1.detail2) CONCAT lower(desc1.detail3) CONCAT lower(desc1.detail4) AS description`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
JOIN desc_table desc1
```

The problem appears to be that you had not defined desc1.

If description is a reserved word, change the name or put it in double quotes.

You may also get slightly better performance using lower around your concatenated strings.

```
lower( a || b || c )
```

Comment: Query changed through policy, in the real query JOIN desc_table desc1 used properly

Comment: lower( a || b || c ) sollution from works Well, thanks WarrenT.

Comment: Personally, I would probably have just used 'd' or 'd1' rather than 'desc1'.  If you're gonna shorten it then why not keep it *short*? But, hey, I'm so lazy I avoid a few extra keystrokes. ;-)